# Xpath works in scrapy shell but not in CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I use Scrapy 2.5.1.

In scrapy shell :

```
fetch(url)    
response.xpath('//a[@data-role="link"]/@data-href').getall()
```

give me some result but, in a class CrawlSpider with Rules and LinkExtractor :

```
class AutoCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'auto_crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['<my site>']
    start_urls = ['<my site>']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@data-role="link"]/data-href'), 
            callback='parse', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        print(f'Crawling {response.url} with HTTP {response.status}')
        Request(url=response.url)
        pass
```

doesn't give me a result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `attrs` in `LinkExtractor`:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@data-role="link"]', attrs='data-href'), callback='parse', follow=True)
```